# populating on the basis of array elements in php

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

This is my code.

```
        if(in_array("1", $mod)){ 
        $res=array('First Name','Insertion','Last Name','Lead Country');}

       if(in_array("2", $mod)){ 
        $res=array('Landline No:','Mobile No:','Lead Country');}

        if(in_array("3", $mod)){ 
        $res=array('City','State','Country','Lead Country');}

        if(in_array("4", $mod)){ 
        $res=array('Email','Lead Country');}

        return $res;
```

Upto this it works fine. But if the array contains more than one value say (1,3)
I need to return both results of 1 and 3.

eg: if the array is like this

```
    array([0]=>1 [1]=>3)
```

then

```
    $res=array('First Name','Insertion','Last Name','City','State','Country','Lead Country')
```

But if there are 2 lead country only one should be displayed how to do this?
Pls help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example that uses a function to add the elements, only if they don't already exist:

```
    function addItems($items, $arr)
    {
        foreach($items as $value)
        {
            if(!in_array($value, $arr))
            {
                $arr[] = $value;
            }
        }

        return $arr;
    }

    $res = array();

    if(in_array("1", $mod)){ 
    $res = addItems(array('First Name','Insertion','Last Name','Lead Country'), $res);}

    if(in_array("2", $mod)){ 
    $res = addItems(array('Landline No:','Mobile No:','Lead Country'), $res);}

    if(in_array("3", $mod)){ 
    $res = addItems(array('City','State','Country','Lead Country'), $res);}

    if(in_array("4", $mod)){ 
    $res = addItems(array('Email','Lead Country'), $res);}

    return $res;
```

Here's another way of doing it which is more OOP and is probably a bit more logical because it doesn't keep passing the whole array back and to, instead it uses an object which holds the array, and has a method to add to it, and get the final result:

```
    class ItemsManager
    {
        protected $items = array();

        public function addItems($items)
        {
            foreach($items as $value)
            {
                if(!in_array($value, $this->items))
                {
                    $this->items[] = $value;
                }
            }
        }

        public function getItems()
        {
            return $this->items;
        }
    }

    $im = new ItemsManager();

    if(in_array("1", $mod)){ 
    $im->addItems(array('First Name','Insertion','Last Name','Lead Country'));}

    if(in_array("2", $mod)){ 
    $im->addItems(array('Landline No:','Mobile No:','Lead Country'));}

    if(in_array("3", $mod)){ 
    $im->addItems(array('City','State','Country','Lead Country'));}

    if(in_array("4", $mod)){ 
    $im->addItems(array('Email','Lead Country'));}

    return $im->getItems();
```

Comment: @Avinash no problem :) I have edited the answer to give another way of doing it which is better I think.

Answer (score 1):

Use `array_merge`:

```
$res = array();
if(in_array("1", $mod)){
    $res=array_merge($res, array('First Name','Insertion','Last Name','Lead Country'));
}

// and so on ...

return $res;
```

Comment: But if there are 2 lead country only one should be displayed how to do this?

Comment: @Avinash `$res = array_unique($res);`  before `return` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Use array_merge to build the result...

```
    $res = array();

    if(in_array("1", $mod)) { 
        $res = array_merge($res, array('First Name','Insertion','Last Name','Lead Country'));
    }

    // etc
```

Comment: But if there are 2 lead country only one should be displayed how to do this?

Comment: array_merge will only add the elements that are not already in the array. That is the point of using it.

Comment: @rikh I think, you are wrong. `array_merge` will add the elements  to array in both cases(Not in array/already exist). If the input arrays have the same string keys(Not values of array), then the later value for that key will overwrite the previous one. If, however, the arrays contain numeric keys, the later value will not overwrite the original value, but will be appended.